# How to suppress row change after cell edit in c# dataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview

After changing value in cell and pressing `enter` cursor jumps down to next cell. Is it possible to avoid this behavior? I want to make cursor stay at same cell after edition accomplishment. I use `CellEndEdit` to perform some action with value in cell.
Thanks!

Comment: That is a natural flow, can you expand on why you want to avoid that or you want it only in some specific scenario

Comment: @V4Vendetta After editing cell in last row it appends new row. I need fixed rows count. It's main reason. But in general I think it would looks better if cursor will stay where edition acted. Jumping down is reasonable if you need to perform sequence of editions one by one. In my case values in cells will edited mostly unoften and quite chaotically.

Comment: you should check out `AllowUserToAddRows` property of the `DataGridView` and set it to false, this will avoid the new row addition part

Comment: @V4Vendetta Thanks, it solves part of problem

Comment: It is achievable but this lead you many errors. Specially your row will not get committed. If you are working on a stand alone application, when you commit a row, cursor moves to next row and it adds a new row to datagrid. But that is actually not a datagrid row. It is just a templet row, so user can start adding data. When cursor moves to new row that row is committed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all I solved my problem in following ***lame*** way.
1. Add global boolean flag to detect if I need to jump up after edit and set it to `false`.
2. In `CellEndEdit` event handler set flag to `true`.
3. In `SelectionChanged` event handler check flag. If it set to `true` then jump up and set flag to `false`.
4. Set `AllowUserToAddRows` to `false` to avoid adding row in case of last row cell edition.

Answer (score 0):

you can restrict it by finding enter key press by  keypress event or cellvaluechanged event